# Why can a selected object not be clicked using _FFClick?

Tags: xpath, autoit

I tried to use the _FFXPath in combination with _FFClick (both part of the ff.au3), but it doesn't click the object:

my relevant code line:

```
$obj = _FFXPath("//div[contains(@class,'jobgroup-9')]", "", 9)
_FFClick($obj)
```

I know that the XPath is correct, because:

```
$pos = _FFGetPosition(_FFXPath("//div[contains(@class,'jobgroup-9')]", "", 9))
```

returns the correct position (I know I can combine with ControlClick, but I don't want it "dirty")